# Division on the last outputs

Tags: vhdl

Counter count the number of input samples. Then the counter output (n) and I want to check if the number of samples is even,then n_of_samples = (n*n) else if odd make that ((n*n)-1)
 will be something like that

```
signal dis : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
signal n   : integer range 0 to 255 :=0;
 if n mod 2=1 then
      n_of samples<= ((n*n)-1);
   else
      n_of_samples <= n*n;
  end if;
    norm_dis <= dis / n_of_samples ;
```

the two signals will have values as (1,6,9,8,.....100) and (0,2,8,9.......,200)
and i want to fetch the two last outputs from the two signal (100,200)
and divide 100/200.how can i write it in vhdl and how can overcome the divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you do not divide by zero!

```
if n_of_samples/=0 then
    norm_dis <= dis / n_of_samples ;
end if;
```